# Angular Universal using assigning a function to the window

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I am trying to assign a function to the window in angular universal.
Initially I did this:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    displayPreferenceModal: any;
  }
}

window.displayPreferenceModal = window.displayPreferenceModal || function () {};
```

And when a user clicked a button I invoked this method:

public openModal(e: any) {
e.preventDefault();

```
window.displayPreferenceModal();
```

}

This worked locally, but not when deployed. I realised it was because I was using angular universal, so I have tried to fix it like this:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    displayPreferenceModal: any;
  }
}

export function inokeDisplayPreferenceModal() {
  return typeof window !== 'undefined'
    ? (window.displayPreferenceModal =
        window.displayPreferenceModal || new Function())
    : new Function();
}
```

Which I add as a provider to my module:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'displayPreferenceModal',
    useFactory: inokeDisplayPreferenceModal,
  },
],
```

and then I updated my component method to this:

```
public openModal(e: any) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) return;

  this.displayPreferenceModal();
}
```

Again, this works locally and this time when deployed it throws no errors, but when clicking the button nothing happens.
I have a console log and it returns and anonymous function :(

Does anyone know what I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ts:3.9.7/angular:8.2.4

Add these code to main.ts

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    foo: any;
  }
}
window.foo =
  window.foo ||
  function () {
    console.log("OK!");
  };
```

It works well! I have tested it both in development mode and deployed in nginx